# Enabling CPF in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I wanted to understand the impact of enabling CPF - Content Processing Framework on Marklogic 4.2.9 server. 
We have a production DB of the size of 3TB and we are looking at various content enrichment and content deletion tasks which need several actions to be performed.
I have worked on creating CFP pipelines in previous projects but in my current project the DB currently has CPF diabled. What I wanted to understand is,
When/if we enable CPF on this DB, what will be the impact on
1. Marklogic memory usage
2. Disk space
3. Performance over all
4. IO etc
The pipelines that we are trying to create will be impacting all/any document existing in the DB.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think @mblakele covers impact on mem and disk quite well. But I'd like to add a few words on how CPF works. That might help on how performance is generally influenced by CPF..

CPF relies on the trigger mechanism of MarkLogic. Any document insert, update and delete activates CPF handling with an initial status transition. Each action causes an additional status transition. Each status transition involves the execution of a post-commit trigger, calling some CPF internal code that does an xdmp:invoke of the actual action module. So, if you have a single transaction inserting 100 docs, this causes 100 post-commit tasks to be queued in the task server queue for starters. And I'm afraid that the xdmp:invokes cause another 100 tasks to be queued. That number multiplies at least by three if documents traverse three statusses on average.

In other words, CPF has a big impact on the task server queue. To what extend that actually impact the performance may depend on how heavily you are already using the task server. Any non-CPF task on the task server is going to be delayed by the CPF tasks. On the other hand, if you aren't really using the task server at the moment, you might not notice to much about this. App server requests run on the app server queue, which is handled separately.

One other thing is that CPF treats document individually. That is ideal for slow and resilient background processing. But if you need speed, you better create transactions for batches of documents.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

If you already have `maintain-last-modified` enabled, the impact on memory and disk space will be minimal. If `maintain-last-modified` was disabled, CPF will create new property fragments as documents are touched. From this you can expect to use additional memory and disk space, probably about 100-B of memory and 1-kB of disk space per document. The extra fragments may also have an impact on I/O and overall performance, but predicting its extent would require deeper understanding of the application and its queries.